# How to getting this value of dynamically-added checkboxes into a hidden content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on this demo. How can I get the value of `$(this)` or even checked element when dynamically adding some checkboxes to a hidden content like bootstrap modal?

```js
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {

  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    $('.modal-body').append('<input type="radio" name="addOD" value="item' + i + '" />');
  }
})

$('input:radio[name=addOD]').on('click', function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
  var val = $('input:radio[name=lenseopttype]:checked').val();
  console.log(val);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/9929600/125981 for events related

Comment: Just to be clear the answer lies with the appended input element in your event handler and adding the click event handler to that (where the event handler is attached)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the inputs are dynamically added, change your on click handler to something like this.

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', 'input:radio[name=addOD]', function () {
        console.log($(this).val());
        var val = $('input:radio[name=lenseopttype]:checked').val();
        console.log(val);
    });
});
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements) will help explain it a bit further

Comment: "What is this?"  "Why does this solve my problem?"  Please add more explination to your solution.

Comment: Change your click event to use $(document).on('click'....

Comment: Not me.  The OP.  The OP may not understand what that form of `on()` is, and why it solves the problem.  Solving the problem is half of an answer.  Explaining to the OP how it solves the issue, is the other half.

Comment: If a link explains your answer, then your answer is a duplicate.

Comment: The question and answer are duplicates.  And your answer explains the solution much less than the other answers that already exist on the site.  It does solve the issue, which is the only reason I'm not downvoting it.  But again, simply saying "this fixes it" is the mark of a low quality answer.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. I'm learning. I do appreciate you explaining your actions.